# Macbook ssh hangs

Tags: macos, ssh

I cannot use ssh to connect to any remote server through the terminal of my macbook right now. It hangs after typing the password. *ssh -vvv* will hang during the following message:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: Checking for xauth using /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/4q/84bx28ld3dd7w9bgzl28q1hr0000gn/T//xauth_test exit > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

debug2: x11_get_proto: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/4q/84bx28ld3dd7w9bgzl28q1hr0000gn/T//ssh-vrmRFGwKUePV/xauthfile generate /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.hQig8mkeOv/org.macports:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 2>/dev/null
```

Do you know the solution to this? If you have anything in mind that want me to try, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to send the 'ForwardX11Trusted' option

you can set it to 'yes' in your .ssh/config file for that host

or you can set -Y on the ssh command line

Answer (score 0):

Al help solved my problem, but my solution is slightly different.  I had `ForwardX11` and no `ForwardX11Trusted` in my `~/.ssh/config`. By taking out `ForwardX11`, ssh works.

So, unless you are using remote X11 application, both `ForwardX11` and `ForwardX11Trusted` should set to `No` (or removed from ~/.ssh/config)